# Click-through relevancy ranking

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to implement click-through relevancy ranking in a search (solr). Basically depending on the users' feedback (which are clicks), we want to change the ordering of search results. Following is my approach.

*We will add a new field to document to index the queries for which result/document has been accessed (or clicked). Whenever a result is clicked, we will update the index to include the query for which the result has been clicked. We will use solr's partial updates to add the new query to the index. Since, we use index as our data-store as well, all our fields are stored and I can afford to store one more field.*

Is this the right approach to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I, yet have to evaluate logging, and it is (yet) away from implementing it. I was just building a requirement specification to start with, which I formulated. 
It is as follows.

```
Evaluate user selection (Click through) for `query` and matched result position.
```

The position is important because it determines the relevancy.

I chose the top results to be 3. (Assume `N=3`).

1. If users are selecting something that has a `N>3`, it is important to increase this result boost for the query.
2. If the position is at `N<=3`, we're good.
3. If position is consistantly at `N<=3`, demote the top results (maybe?)

However, we may get a lot of wrong info, here. Assume, a single user went crazy and clicks absolutely irrelevant results.

So we need to monitor usage, and log even user events, apart from just the basic position and click through to cover this.

So, log needs to be on :

- Clicks results per page per `{user-login|session}`.
- Click on result for `{Query + Filters + Facets}`. A special flag for `{did you mean... | autocomplete}` click events, with `{TimeStamp + Location}`

If a significant number of unique users indicate clicking on low score documents during a time range (months), I would boost the documents according to location.

Since we even have co-related a user session(login), I might be able to map results according to the user (if irrelevant noise generated by user, send it back to him ;P).

However, I would try my best not to put in too much boost. The search may look tampered.

Also a feedback form for the users to fill in might be a good idea to see how well you are going.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.. I wanted to know, how do you use the information that you extract from logs? Do you put that information back into the index the way I proposed? or fetch results from the index and then do some post-processing which I think is not very efficient.

Comment: As I said, implementation is left, but one of two options : 1. Using Another Field containing query tokens (and update only that field every log dump), 2. Update Field Boost (Once every 24-48 hours). I never cared about indexing efficiency, since my index is < 1Gb.